# Fetch ID of a model and save to other model's foreign key field in django

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a User model using AbstractBaseUser. I have a model Employee using Model class. I want that when a user is created through sign up, the user inherits all the fields of Employee model. I have made a OnetoOne relation between User model and Employee. But after creating an user when I query employee model, I can not find any data related to the created User.
User manager:

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email and password.
    """
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self, email,username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            username=username
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            password=password,
            username=username
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

User:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    """
    Creates a customized database table for user
    """
    email = models.EmailField(
        verbose_name='email address',
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email',]

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
```

I have extended the user model with a OnetoOne relation using `OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)`

```
Employee model:

    class Employee(models.Model):
        """
        Create employee attributes
        """
        employee_user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
        e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=False)
        first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse("employee:employee-list")
```

I do not want to use signal decorator. I want to pass raw query meaning I want to feetch User ID and pass it to Employee table's employee_user field
. what should be my query in django ORM?

Comment: Sorry, but where are you creating an `Employee` records per user creation? Your one-to-one field allowed to be `null` and that's what actually seems to be happening.

Comment: I did not create any Employee records per user creation. How can I do that?

Comment: If you don't wont to use signals, then other option is to override user model `save` method and explicitly create `Employee` records one's user will be saved (have an PK).

Comment: How can I override save method?

Answer (score 0):

Signals solve a specific problem: it decouples two entities that may have to work together. If you already have coupled models and full control over them, you don't need signals but just talk directly to each other.

In this case, don't create a user and do something complex. Keep it simple and create an employee. Also, from your story it seems that user data is not optional for an employee, but an employee is a special user. So, use [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

```py
from myapp.models import User


class Employee(User):
    # more fields
    # This inherits the manager from User: objects = UserManager()
```

In your employee sign up, you simply create an employee and take care of the extra form data:

```py
class SignupView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = ModelFormWithEmployeeFields

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.validated_data
        username = data.pop('username')
        password = data.pop('password')
        email = data.pop('email')
        employee = self.model.objects.create_user(username, password, email, **data)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

However, for you this won't work as you've crippled the UserManager:

```py
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, password=None):
        ...
```

It should accept arbitrary keyword arguments to be passed `Manager.create()`, like in BaseUserManger and then everything automatically falls into place.

Comment: Every user is employee in my case.

Comment: Then just name your custom user model Employee, add the extra fields straight on the model and move on. You're already using a custom user model anyway.

Comment: I am using employee model for a modelform also. Using that form I am trying to invite new users.